# Is there a way of getting the location of where a script tag is being called?

Tags: html

I'm trying to make an HTML page, and made an easy way to sort of creating complicated elements, which returns a DOM element. But I don't know how to append the element into the appropriate position. For example, I want to use the function in between the paragraphs in my `<body>` but I don't know how.

Here is an example:

```html
<body>
p1
<br>
p2
<br>
<script>document.getlocation().append(DOM element)</script>
<br>
p3
</body>
```

should yield

```
p1
p2
DOM element
p3
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, including documentations, and or code, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write).

```
<body>
p1
<br>
p2
<br>
<script>document.write('<p>DOM Element</p>');</script>
<br>
p3
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a tag in your html where you want to insert the element or text. Grab it and then either change the innerHTML or append children.  if the latter you may want to use a p or div tag instead of span.

```js
var sp = document.getElementById('here');
sp.style.display='block';
sp.innerHTML='DOM Element';
```

```html
<body>
p1
<br>
p2
<br>
<span id='here'></span>
p3
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

After looking at your desired result, I notice multiple mistakes in your code. First of all, `DOM element` must be enclosed in quotes, single or double, to treat it as a string.

Second, `document.getlocation()` is not a function. What you actually need to do to place `'DOM element'` at the location where the script is being called it to use `document.write()`.

```
<body>
p1
<br>
p2
<br>
<script>document.write('DOM element');</script>
<br>
p3
</body>
```

This would successfully give the desired output. Similar to `echo` in PHP, `document.write()` can be used to write data to the document where the script is called.

Comment: oh yeah i didn't really mean it as a string of sorts but rather a sort of pseudocode for an actual dom element.

Comment: So do you want to add another element to this element? You can use tags inside the string too. For example, `document.write('<b>Bold</b>')` would write the text `Bold` inside `b` tags to make it bold.

Answer (score 0):

I would give each of your HTML elements an id, and then proceed as in the code below. I have given you 2 example methods and links to the documentation to try.
Hope that helps :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <p id="id1">p1</p>
    <br id="id2">
    <p id="id3">p2</p>
    <br id="id4">
    <br id="id5">
    <p id="id6">p3</p>

    <script>

        // Example 1: create element and insert before another element:
        // See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore
        let newElement1 = document.createElement('p');
        newElement1.innerText='New paragraph 1';

        let el3 = document.getElementById('id3');
        document.body.insertBefore(newElement1, el3);

        // Example 2: create an element and use the insertAdjacentElement function:
        // See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement
        let newElement2 = document.createElement('p');
        newElement2.innerText='New paragraph 2';

        let el5 = document.getElementById('id5');
        el5.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', newElement2);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```